# How to hide the previous flash message while calling another function - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flash

I want to hide the flash message of function1 inside function2 while calling function2.

I have given the timeout to fade out the flash message. But need to fade out the flash message of particular function inside another function before time out.

```
$scope.function1 = function() {
var response = {
                "json": 
                  {
                   "response": 
                     {
                      "status": "Success"
                     }
                  }
               };

               if (response.success != undefined) {
                   FlashService.Success(response.message);
                   window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                   $timeout(function(){
                      delete $rootScope.flash;
                   }, 9000);
               } else {
                     if(response.json.response.status == "Success") {
                        FlashService.Success("Updated successfully", true);
                        window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                        $timeout(function(){
                           delete $rootScope.flash;
                        }, 9000);
                     } else {
                        FlashService.Success(response.json.response.status);
                        window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                        $timeout(function(){
                           delete $rootScope.flash;
                        }, 9000);
                     }
                  }
              };

$scope.function2 = function() {
     console.log("Inside function2");
};

$scope.function1();



<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="function2()">Call</button>
```

Comment: you tagged this [flash] ... do you use adobe's cross platform runtime called flash?

Comment: Adobe's cross platform means?

Comment: Do you know what Flash is?

Comment: Flash is an alert message to the user about status of the function error or success

Comment: ahh, that's what *you* call `flash` - if you hover over the flash TAG in your question, you'll see that tag refers to **Adobe's cross-platform multimedia platform** - my bad

Comment: I need to display the error or success flash message of the particular function inside the particular div. To other div, I should not display the error or success message of other divs or functions

Comment: yes, that was your question, I mistakenly thought this had to do with Adobe Flash due to your tagging the question with the Flash tag that refers to Adobe Flash. Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: No problem. Can you suggest me any solution